# python,epoll.register(fd, eventmask) only has two parameters, how could I to use event.data_ptr like c++?

Tags: python, c++, epoll

I use python's `epoll` but it can't use `event.data.ptr` like in c++.

Sometimes I will register class `A.fd` and sometimes I will register class `B.fd`.

So, when `epoll.poll()` returned, how can I know whether `fd` belongs to class `A` or `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always maintain a separate map from `fd` to `A` or `B`. Then when an event gets triggered, lookup based on `fd`.
Doesn't look like `epoll` has a richer interface, even in Python 3+

Comment: thanks,it is really  has not  a richer interface, even in python 3.7....i will try to use a map to lookup.